# Join two tables on date version

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables: table `SAMPLES`, which contains samples, sample codes, and sample dates, and Table `CODES`, which contains sample codes, prices, and a from_date which is the date from which the price is applicable. I need to join these two tables and return correct price based on the sample date.

CODES

```
SEQ_NUM NAME    VERSION FROM_DATE         PRICE
1       CODE_A  1       2010-03-01 00:00  90
2       CODE_A  2       2011-10-07 00:00  95
3       CODE_A  3       2012-05-08 00:00  99
4       CODE_A  4       2015-06-17 00:00  110
5       CODE_B  1       2012-04-01 00:00  10
6       CODE_B  2       2014-07-07 00:00  20
```

SAMPLES

```
SAMPLE_NUMBER   SAMPLE_ID   SAMPLE_CODE SAMPLE_DATE
1               ABC12       CODE_A      2010-04-01 00:00
2               ABC13       CODE_A      2015-10-07 00:00
3               ABC14       CODE_A      2012-06-09 00:00
4               ABC15       CODE_B      2014-10-12 00:00
```

I can get the correct price for a specific sample with:

```
select MAX(s.SAMPLE_NUMBER), MAX(c1.PRICE_COLLECT), MAX(c1.NAME)
from CODES c1  
left join CODES c2 on (c1.SEQ_NUM = c2.SEQ_NUM and c1.VERSION < c2.VERSION)
inner join sample s on s.SAMPLE_CODE = c1.NAME 
where c2.SEQ_NUM is null  
and c1.FROM_DATE < s.SAMPLED_DATE 
and s.SAMPLE_NUMBER = 3
```

RESULT

```
s.SAMPLE_NUMBER c1.PRICE    c1.NAME
3               99          CODE_A
```

But I would like to get the entire result set like:

```
s.SAMPLE_NUMBER c.PRICE c.NAME
1               90      CODE_A
2               110     CODE_A
3               99      CODE_A
4               20      CODE_B
```

Is there a way to do this in a single SQL statement?

Comment: Then you can remove that `s.SAMPLE_NUMBER = 3` from query, right ?

Comment: Yes + adding: group by SAMPLE_NUMBER, c1.NAME did the trick. Thank you.